# How can I copy the rotation of an posed bone of an armature to an unrelated object?

Tags: modeling

I have a machinery, which is already posed somehow.
I need its current rotation in space to another object, which is neither
child nor parent of this bone/armature.
Instead this object is a "vertex child" of another mesh.

Copy Rotation and Copy Visual Rotation did not work for me.

How can I do this?

Here is a blend file, which reproduce the problem...

[image]

Comment: Could you add more detail about what is not working with copy rotation?

Comment: I select first the object then the bone. Then I do "Copy Rotation" and I does nothing. Same for "Copy Visual Rotation"....or what kind of detail do you refer to?(...I am no native speaker...may be I get something totally wrong here...sorry. :) )

Comment: Could you upload the part that is not working using this link https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? That will avoid misunderstanding : )

Comment: Unfortunately not. The file is not my own...I am only working on it.

Comment: I understand. But could you simply reproduce the test case with other objects and another file?

Comment: I've the file, thanks. Though, I don't understand: you just want the empty to copy rotation of the bone? You can just add a constraint to do that? And, what about the "vertex child" in your question? Or this is the opposite: you want the bone to copy rotation of the empty??

Comment: Yes, the empty should oriented like the bone. A constraint does not work in this case...the copied orientation is permanent - kinda starting point and nothing, which should be done permanently while the animation is running.

Comment: Just adding a constraint to the empty (copy rotation), works perfectly here... so? I don't know. Which version of Blender are you using? (but I don't think this have ever been broken whatever the version is)